# Display larger indentation for files that are indented with just two spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project that is using 2 spaces as indentation.
I have a hard time reading code with such small indentation, so my question is:

Question: Can I make vscode **show** the two spaces as if they were wider (for example double the width)?

(I could of course solve it in a hackish way, by converting each file on checkout, and convert it back before i commit it, but that would be very tedious and error prone. I could also try to convince the project to convert the whole project to tabs, so that everyone can use their own preferred indentation. But I don't want to go into that discussion for every project I work on :) )

Answer (score 1):

I have written the extension [Indent Whitespace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-indentWhitespace) that decorates each space used in indentation with additional spaces (cursor will skip the decoration).

The decorated spaces are colored with a very transparent red.

[image]

With a setting you can change the number of spaces to add, default 1.

If you delete spaces with `Delete` it looks funny because the selection does not change, use the Arrow keys to update the decorations.

In a later version I will make the decoration color a setting, and also only update the decoration when the file changes (only important for large files, and fix the delete-update rendering).

Comment: Since your `backGroundColor` can take a `ThemeColor`, you might choose to just contribute that color in your `package.json`.  Cleaner and simpler than making another setting.  If you enable `Discussions` on your repository I can show code if you want it.

Comment: @Mark Discussions enabled (did not know this feature). I think it has to be a color different from a ThemeColor, you must be able to see it is a dummy space not any of the theme/syntax colors

Comment: You can create your own ThemeColor - anything you want.

Comment: @Mark Contribute my own Theme color, you can customize it in the usual method, good tip

Comment: Cool! Seems like the behavior is a bit strange at the beginning of a line though. Place cursor just before the first letter, and the type a letter, then the text jumps weirdly.

Comment: @foolo it is the same behavior you have in a CSS file where you have the color decoration, you can't place the cursor **on** a decoration. At the moment the decorator is **after** the space, if you place the cursor before the first character you have the decorator between the cursor and the character, type a character and it will appear after the decorator, if I place the decorator **before** the space it looks weird if you select a line, I will add a setting so the user can decide before/after the space.

Comment: Sounds good! A decorator before the space might be better, so a setting should be fine.

Comment: @foolo try v0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.
There is no such setting in VS Code. As of [version 1.13](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_letter-spacing), you can change the *kerning*, but this changes the spacing between all characters. You cannot do this only for a single character (or a set of characters).

The space width is a property of the font. Microsoft has a [guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/develop/character-design-standards/whitespace) that defines what is the ideal space size for a font. But this does not mean you cannot change it yourself when designing one. So I created a version of Roboto Mono which space character is 4x the original one.

This works on Notepad and MS Word, we can see the space is quite big. However, using the exact same font in VS Code, the space is still small, independently of the font being [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) or not.

**Illustration**

[image]

Somehow, it looks like VS Code ignores space size in the font and decides by itself what is the best value.